# Do I need to guess from here on this sudoku?

Tags: sudoku

I keep staring at this sudoku puzzle and can't seem to find the next move.

[image]

Is the next move a guessing move? I thought sudoku always has clear solutions, you just need to figure them out.

Comment: I think your initial numbers are already wrong..

Comment: Can you be more specific? I don't think I've made a mistake. My numbers are written in blue

Comment: It might be useful to update your image without the little hint/guess grey numbers, as they are confusing. E.g. the top right set of 9 squares has 2 squares with a little 4, and two with a little 7. Just keep the large black numbers (the starting ones) and the blue ones (your input).

Comment: @Adelin - thank you. I have been able to replay from the start to your current position, except for the 2/7/5 in column 1, and the 5 in column 2. Could you shed some light on how you arrived at those? R6C1 can be 2/5/7, R5C1 can be 2/5, and R7C1 and R6C2 can both be 5/7.

Comment: `5` is for sure in R6C1, dicatated by top middle 3x3 cell. There, you can have `8` and `3` exclusively in the R1 C4 respectively C5, which tells us that the remaining `1` and `5` are on R3, therefore telling us that the `5` in top left 3x3 cell is on C3 which, working togheter with the `5` from R8C6, cuts the bottom left 3x3 in such a way that `5` is only possible in R6C1. The remaining two (`7` and `2`) are easy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No you shouldn't guess. The puzzle has a unique solution. However, you can't continue unless you calculate all possibilities. Once you do that, solving the puzzle will be easy. I have added the possibilities below. If you want to do that on your own, don't look down.

> [image: Sudoko possibilities]

Once you do that, I think the next step is clear:

> [image: Next step]

Note:

> others pointed out in the comments that it is unclear why that particular cell cannot have a 5. To explain, in the red column there are 2 cells indicated in blue. They have two possibilities: (3,5). No matter how the possibilities are distributed, any of the cells will definitely have a 3 and the other a 5. Which makes it impossible for any other cell in that column to have a 3 or a 5. 
>
>  [image: explanation]

Additional explanation (requested by the OP):

> Why can't there be a 7 in the last row? Because it can only be in row
>  7.Explained below: [image: additional explanation]

Comment: How is it clear that in that place it's a 7? Why is it not a 5?

Comment: @Adelin if you look at thd possible numbers at that cell, you can see there is only a 7. What makes you think there should be a 5

Comment: What makes you think there _shouldn't_ be a 5 in that cell? Nothing around it prevents that cell from containing 5.

Comment: @Adelin I have updated the answer with the proper explanation.

Comment: @VotBear, thanks for the remark please see the updated answer

Comment: @Mhmd - your additional note is not true either. You can have a `3` on row 5, col 7 and a `5` on row 9 col 9, thus allowing to have a `5` on row 2, col 8

Comment: @Adelin no it is not possible. What will the value of row 9 column 8 be then? When you have two cells in the way explained above they are called naked pairs: https://www.sudokuoftheday.com/techniques/naked-pairs-triples/

Comment: row 9 col 8 can be a `3`

Comment: @Adelin I don't think you understood the point. You have to look only a column 8. In a sudoku any column should have the numbers from 1 to 9 only once. If we apply this concept to **column 8** we can see the cells in row 5 and 9 can have only the values of 3 and 5. If one of them is 3 the other should definitely be a 5. If you are still confused, please look at the link in the above comment to know more about naked pairs.

Comment: actually on column 8 you can have a `3` on row 8 as well, or a `5` on row 4. Why not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71762/discussion-between-mhmd-and-adelin).

Comment: Accepted as it IS the right answer, but not a very good explanation. The trick here was to understand that indeed `3` and `5` can exclusively be in R5C7, respectively R9C7. You might argue that on R9C7 can be a `7` as well, but that's ruled out by the fact that `7` in that grid can only be in R7C7 or R7C9. That being said, `7` is indeed positioned at R2C7.

Comment: Ah, that clarifies it. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: The 7s in row 7 don't look right. 7 can't be the only possibility in two places in the same row/box. Your chart must be incomplete, or I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: @chipster if you focus on the 7th row, 7 can't be in the 5th column. For that, it can only be in one of the other two places. It doesn't matter what pther numbers are there, if we focus on 7 we know it is going to be in row 7 in the lower right box.

Answer (score 0):

For a start:

> 2,4 and 7 cannot be in the middle square bottom row, which means that there has to be 1 and 6.

This, in turn, means that:

> the 8 must be in the top middle and that there must be a 5 to the middle left in the middle square, and so on.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! This question already had an answer accepted 11 months ago - be sure to read other answers to make sure you aren't duplicating content.